# Organize the results of an script

Tags: applescript

The result of a script gives me something that, simplified, looks like this:

```
{{"First", "Second"}, {"Third", "Fourth"}}
```

I would like to show it in an easy way for the user. Something like this:
List 1: First, Second
List 2: Third, Fourth

I know that there are only two levels of nested information. But I do not know how many lists or items inside each list.

How can I show the result of the script in a clear, easy way to the user?

Comment: Why the negative point?. Please, tell me what I should improve

Comment: Are you wanting the results to be [***`pretty printed`***](https://paste.ee/p/tpNDg) ?

Comment: Is there a possibility that your result, (whose class is a `list`), may contain further nested list(s). For instance; `{{"1st", "2nd"}, {"3rd", "4th", {"5th", "6th"}}}` - _(Note the third item of the second list is another list containing two text items namely `5th` & `6th` )_. If _"yes"_ how should this type of scenario be shown in your desired result? Given that you seem to be using the term "Group" to mean `list`, and given the possibility of multiple nested list(s), should these be labelled  _SubGroup 1: ... etc_, and also how should further `list` nesting (_n_ levels deep) be presented?

Comment: @RobC As I say in my question, there are only two levels of nested information. Only one list inside the other, like in the example I provide. The question is that I do not know how many lists there is in each level.

Comment: @Nrc, Per you comment to me, I wouldn't worry too much about getting down votes. The very first question I posted got down voted and I kept going. Personally, I do not see anything wrong type question you've asked. Possible reasons for down votes can be a lack of research or no research shown, or a question is not clear.  Based on those reasons as well as some of the comments, I'd suggest you edit your question so there are no ambiguities as to what is or can be returned. Cont...

Comment: ...Cont. What you show as an example of what is returned is a list containing two lists and from "**I know that there are only two levels of nested information. But I do not know how many "groups" or elements inside each group.**" it is not clear how may lists can be contain it the returned list or how may list items can exist in any of the lists, the list returned or the list item lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will build out the message to be displayed **regardless of how many lists are returned**.

Since you've not included any *code*, I'm setting basic *variables* to handle the overall process.

```
set theLists to {{"First", "Second"}, {"Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"}, ¬
    {"Sixth", "Seventh"}, {"Eight", "Ninth", "Tenth", "Eleventh"}}

set theListCount to count theLists
set theMsg to ""

set text item delimiters to ", "

repeat with i from 1 to theListCount
    if i < theListCount then
        set theMsg to theMsg & "Group " & i & ": " & item i of theLists & linefeed
    else
        set theMsg to theMsg & "Group " & i & ": " & item i of theLists
    end if
end repeat

set text item delimiters to ""

display dialog theMsg buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
```

Using `theLists` *variable* set at the start of the *script* to represent the `lists` *returned* and a dummy set of `list items` and build up a message to use with the `display dialog`, the following image is as example of what is returned by the *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

[image: display dialog]

Obviously if you have a large number of `lists` and `lists items` a `display dialog` is not going to be the way to go, so this is just an example of how to *enumerate* the `list` and will need different coding to be displayed in another manner, however this hopefully will put you on the right track.

Otherwise you need to be a bit more explicit and specific, maybe even include some *code* as appropriate.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thank you I am new with Applescript and this helps me to orientate my efforts. On the other side, do you know why the negative point? The question seems very complicated to me and I did not find any guide for a beginner like me on Google. Perhaps I should not ask this kind of questions at all?